# Start Jenkins build using batch script

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am working with a Jenkins build server to run synthesis/simulation for FPGAs.
Right now I have nightly builds and can start the build manually in Jenkins browser interface.

My question is:

**Is there any possibility to start a job build with a batch script without using browser interface?**

(I am running Jenkins on Windows 7 64bit.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is an example with a curl command (for a job with parameters):

```
curl -X POST -u YOUR_USER:YOUR_USER_PASSWORD http://YOUR_JENKINS_URL/job/YOUR_JOB/buildWithParameters?PARAM1=value1&PARAM2=value
```

And a job without parameters:

```
curl -X POST -u YOUR_USER:YOUR_USER_PASSWORD http://YOUR_JENKINS_URL/job/YOUR_JOB/build
```

If you don't want to use your user/password, you can generate an API token for your Jenkins user:

[image]

And use this token in your curl command:

```
curl -X POST http://YOUR_JENKINS_URL/job/YOUR_JOB/build?TOKEN=YOUR_API_TOKEN
```

Comment: As proposed by @tony19 below, you can also generate an API token for your user (if you don't want to use the user/password). I've updated my answer. Happy to know it solved your problem :)

Comment: Is it possible to pass SVN Url's with parameters, too? It would be nice to tell Jenkins via command line to run a specific job (in my case synthesis for FPGAs) and checkout all projects from SVN. My Python script in Jenkins is able to run every checkout in workspace folder for FPGA synthesis, but I want to keep it simple for my users to start the jobs with a single batch and their specific checkouts.

Comment: If you have one parameter per SVN url, you can pass them using the command line (maybe protected with double quotes).

Comment: This could be an opportunity, thank you! Do you know any other plugins or commands to pass them to Jenkins? Is passing parameters a good way to solve this?

Comment: I've created a room to discuss of that if you want: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108894/discussion-with-michi-b

Comment: I'd like to discuss, but I need 20 reputation to talk in chats... :/

Comment: Ho sorry :( If I find another solution for your SVN url(s), I'll post a message here.

Answer (score 14):

You can trigger a Jenkins job with a configured token instead of your username/password, which would allow you to share a trigger script without exposing your own credentials.

1. Go to your job's configuration.
2. Scroll down to **Build Triggers**, and check the box for **Trigger build remotely (e.g., from scripts)**, and enter an authentication token (e.g., "MY_TOKEN").

[image]

3. Copy one of the URLs below the **Authentication Token** field based on whether your build has parameters.

Then use that URL in a [`curl`](http://man.cx/curl) command to trigger a build. For example:

```
curl -I https://${JENKINS_URL}/job/tmp/job/dummy-test/build?token=MY_TOKEN
```

The `-I` parameter tells `curl` to print the head of the response, which you could use to determine the result status. Jenkins replies with **HTTP 201** if successful:

```
$ curl -I https://<JENKINS_URL>/job/tmp/job/dummy-test/build\?token\=MY_TOKEN
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Cache-Control: public
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 11 Apr 2016 12:47:26 GMT
Location: https://<JENKINS_URL>/queue/item/1707/
Pragma: public
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 3):

As I tried to trigger my job via curl I ended up always getting "Not authorized" errors.

Later I found out that this was because I completely disabled anonymous access on the server. The solution was to install the following plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Token+Root+Plugin

Source: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17764

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using curl command with -I Option. create an API token for the jenkins Job and use it to trigger the job. you can use jenkins user password for this as well.

[image]

command would be

```
curl -I -u auto:<user_api_token> http://<jenkins_Server>/job/test/build?token=wefiytgwiefiweihfqweiodf
```

results would be
[image]

for more information 
https://serverfault.com/questions/888176/how-to-trigger-jenkins-job-via-curl-command-remotely/888248#888248

Answer (score 1):

In the new Jenkins Pipeline, under *Build Triggers*, select the checkbox *Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)*.  Then give Jenkins a token that will be required when triggering the build.

#### `Not authorized` errors

A problem with triggering the builds remotely is, if you've set up Jenkins right and disabled anonymous user access, you will get `Not authorized` errors when you try to trigger the build from a script (as @keocra pointed out).  You now have two options:

1. Pass a username and password along when you trigger the build.  This means that your script will need to include the username and password, which means everyone who can read your script will have the username and password, which is almost as bad as anonymous access.
2. Use the [Build Token Root Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-token-root).  This plugin allows you to use the *Trigger builds remotely* feature without requiring the username and password.  All you need is the token you generated before.

#### Triggering the build

To trigger the build remotely, run

```
curl JENKINS_URL/buildByToken/build?job=JobFoo&token=MyToken
```

Where `JENKINS_URL` is the URL to your Jenkins instance, `JobFoo` is the name of your job, and `MyToken` is the token you entered under *Trigger bulids remotely*.

Of course, you don't need to use `curl`; you can also use `wget` or any other program that can make HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

I've googled across many addresses and the working result can be found here:

```
#!/bin/bash
TOKEN='jenkins-user-token'
USER='my-username'
SERVER="http://your.server.address"

#jenkins job parameters
PARAMF=$1
SECONDPARAM=$2

# retrieve the crumb that we need to pass in the header
CRUMBS=$(curl -s -X GET -u $USER:$TOKEN ${SERVER}/crumbIssuer/api/json  | jq -c '. | .crumb ')
curl --user $USER:$TOKEN  -H "Jenkins-Crumb:${CRUMBS}" -X POST  "${SERVER}/view/MyView/job/JobName/buildWithParameters?TOKEN=${TOKEN}&PARAMETERONE=${PARAMF}&PARAMETERTWO=${SECONDPARAM}"
```

The steps script does:

1. get the breadcrumb
2. call jenkins to execute a job with multiple parameters

you can save this script as jenkins-job-cli.sh and call it

```
chmod +x jenkins-job-cli.sh
./jenkins-job-cli.sh first-parameter second-parameter
```

Hope this help.

Cheers,

Leslie

Comment: `crumbIssuer/api` doesn't work for jenkins 2.176+ due to CSRF security improvements. More details available here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.176/#SECURITY-626

Answer (score 0):

**Fast Forward to 2023**

You need to pass 2 tokens to execute your job remotely from a script/bash.
You need:

1. apiToken to authenticate your identity. This value is created from JENKINS_URL/me/configure . Also check [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/authenticating-scripted-clients/) for documentation
2. Another Job authentication token which you create when you enable 'Trigger builds remotely'.

Below is a sample to execute job with 2 parameters, you can tweak to get your done.

```bash
PARAM1_VALUE=<param1_value>
PARAM2_VALUE=<param2_vale>
USERNAME=dummy_user_name
JENKINS_URL="http://10.xxx.x.xxx:8080"
JOB_TOKEN="<value>" # you create this token when you enable Job>Configure>Build Triggers>Trigger builds remotely
LOGIN_API_TOKEN="<value>" #get this value from JENKINS_URL/me/configure 

curl -L --user $USERNAME:$LOGIN_API_TOKEN "$JENKINS_URL/job/JobName/buildWithParameters?token=$JOB_TOKEN&param1_name=$PARAM1_VALUE&param2_name=$PARAM2_VALUE"
```