# API to kick of a jenkins build/CI job?

Tags: curl, jenkins

I want an API that i can curl to kick of a jenkins build/CI job via the job name.
Is there such an API available out of the box for jenkins?

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API ?

Comment: I was using curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build --user xxx:xxx

Comment: its giving error. I might be doing it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've posted a solution with the Jenkins REST API and Curl here 2 hours ago:
[Start Jenkins build using batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548690/start-jenkins-build-using-batch-script)

Here is an example to trigger a job with two parameters:

```
curl -X POST -u YOUR_USER:YOUR_USER_PASSWORD http://YOUR_JENKINS_URL/job/YOUR_JOB/buildWithParameters?PARAM1=value1&PARAM2=value
```

Comment: Please include the substantial information in your answer.