# How so start a Jenkins job from another jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ant

I am working with Ant and using jenkins to make builds.

SO, I am using jenkins and build.xml for a job. But I want to call another job in my build.xml to call another job in a different jenkins.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: The below thread might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439880/run-a-jenkins-job-on-another-jenkins-instance-from-the-jenkins-job

Comment: I cannot use plugins. Is there another way?

Comment: You can use `curl` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553157/api-to-kick-of-a-jenkins-build-ci-job

Answer (score 0):

Using curl you can trigger a remote jenkins job :

curl -X POST http://${user}:${password}@${jenkins_url}/job/${job_name}/build

Have a look at this https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218889337-How-to-build-a-job-using-the-REST-API-and-cURL-

Now, to execute this curl from ant/build.xml, use exec task of ant.

Comment: I tried that but I get "curl: (6) Could not resolve host: http".

Comment: Now I've tried some solutions but still didn't manage to make this work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967855/curl-6-could-not-resolve-host-google-com-name-or-service-not-known