# Run test cases in jenkins using java program

Tags: jenkins, testng

I have developed a webpage.In that i have a button. I want to run test cases in jenkins after clicking the button.How do i run testng testcases in Jenkins programatically ?

Comment: all what you want to do is on clicking button need to schedule job in jenkins, this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548690/start-jenkins-build-using-batch-script helps to run Jenkins job in cmd you may trigger this on button click on some thing like this

Comment: in job you can run testng.xml, google it you can easy find it

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configure your job to trigger on that button click and write script to be executed in job config for running test cases.
**OR**
You can integrate your Jenkins with SCM tool.(eg GitHub)
Push your source codes files their, configure your repo with Jenkins.
You can have .xml file with target to run test cases, and u can mention that target in commands section it will run test cases OR instead of .xml file you can write entire script needed to run test cases.
(Additionally you can use github hook feature to trigger this job after new code changes have been done, so it can be tested instantly).

I hope this will give you an idea, feel free to contact if you have any queries.