# triggering jenkins job from cli

Tags: bash, jenkins, continuous-integration

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36548802/3512538), I'm trying to trigger my own Jenkins build.

First, I tried to just connect to Jenkins and GET data from the main page:

```
curl -X GET -u $u:$p http://$ip
```

As expected, this gave me the entire html page.

I tried it again with:

```
curl -X GET -u $u:$p http://$ip/job/$j
```

where `j` is the job I want to trigger (when entering Jenknis, I can select a certain job, and get to a page with this address: http://ip/job/j/)

However, this produced no output (No errors at least)

I then tried clicking on the "build with parameters" tab on Jenkins and saw that the page I navigated to had this suffix on its address: `build?delay=0sec`

so I tried to add it, and again, I got some output.

Now, all of this was just a POC to show I can access the right IP, but when trying to actually trigger the build using POST and basically the same line (i.e. `curl -X POST -u $u:$p http://$ip/job/$j/build?delay=0sec;SOME_PARAM=FOO`) it failed with this output:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /job/hailo_nightly/build. Reason:
<pre>    No valid crumb was included in the request</pre></p><hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.z-SNAPSHOT</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

what am I doint wrong?

*Also tried using `curl --user <your_jenkins_username>:<your_jenkins_API_key> http://<jenkins_server_url>/job/<your_jenkins_job_name>/build` [from here](https://www.ittybittytalks.com/how-to-automate-your-jenkins-build-script/) but that did the same as GET*

Comment: I have no idea about why your approach fails, but maybe this link can help you: https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2015/10/triggering-jenkins-builds-by-url/

Comment: try to change the method to POST and 403 http error is forbidden. Do you have permission to launch the build from jenkins?