# Jenkins job submission from command line and get the status of the job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I need to submit the Jenkins job from command line instead from UI. How to trigger it via command line by passing job parameters and get the status of the job with build number? Any inputs?

Comment: Take a look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548690/start-jenkins-build-using-batch-script) question.

Comment: Thanks for this info. Are there any alterative way to submit the job using payload file and without any tokens?

Comment: The tokens are needed due to security configurations on your server, if your security is not configured (not recommended) then you don't need tokens.